# Query post from all category with same tag on 1 pages

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, tags

How to query posts from categories with specific tags? For Example if I visit "**localhost/tag/tutorial**" the archive page would show all post from all category with tutorial tag.

But the view would be seperated by category. For example:

Category 1

- Category 1 Post 1 With tutorial tag
- Category 1 Post 2 with tutorial tag

Category 2

- Category 2 Post 2 With tutorial tag
- Category 2 Post 10 With tutorial tag

NB: The posts show in each categories with same tags.

I have a code that show latest posts in each categories

```
<?php
        $categories = get_categories();
        foreach($categories as $category) { ?>

        <div class="CategoryPost">
          <h2><?php echo $category->name; ?></h2>
          <ul>
          <?php
            $post_args = array(
              'category' => $category->term_id,
              'numberposts' => 9999,
              'orderby'=> 'post_date',
              'order' => 'ASC',
              'post_type' => 'post'
            );

            $posts = get_posts($post_args);
            foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
              <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><span><?php the_time('d M Y') ?></span> <i class="Seperate">&raquo;</i> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            </ul>
          </div>
        <?php }
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

The code above would show latest posts in each category with this look.

Category 1 Name

- Category 1 Post 1
- Category 1 Post 2

Category 2 Name

- Category 1 Post 1
- Category 1 Post 2

Category 3 Name

- Category 1 Post 1
- Category 1 Post 2

I would like to make a tags archive that work with that template and the posts would be shown in each categories even the posts have the same tags.

Comment: I hope here you will find your answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/281550/list-with-categories-subcategories-and-posts-of-custom-posttype?noredirect=1#comment417844_281550

Comment: overall it looks same, but its looks like the answer from there is to show posts in every category (including main category or sub category). His first code actually works fine but he found a problem that posts with same category show twice (duplicate) which is he want to only show once and not duplicate. For my problem is I want to show posts with same tags (For example: tutorial) and seperate in category. If category 1 and 2 have a posts with tags tutorial it would be shown the post but seperated in their own category

Comment: By making minor tweaks in the code you can use this for your purpose. As, much as I know you have to change the taxonomy only. Rest is up-to you.

Comment: Yup. I think that if I there's 1 more foreach for tags before posts it would be work. But I dont know how to add the query. Honestly its my first time playing with query on wordpress. So I dont know what to do.

Comment: What I want is category 1 show all post but only a post with tutorial tag. It would be work in category 2 and 3 or more category if the post have tutorial tag.

Comment: And I'm really sorry if my english is bad. Because english is not my main language.. *Cheers

Comment: No, you are absolutely wrong on this. You, have to pass `tag` option in the `get_posts` for that.

Comment: I see.. what kind of tag option should I pass?

Comment: `tag` name or id. Please, refer to WordPress codex  https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help to get the category post on tag archive page. Let me know.

```
<?php       

        $current_tag = single_tag_title( $prefix = '', $display = false );
        $categories = get_categories( array('hide_empty' => TRUE) );
        foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
        <?php
            $args=array(
                'posts_per_page' => -1, 
                'tag' => $current_tag,
                'cat' => $category->term_id,
            );

            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

            if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                ?>
                <div class="CategoryPost">
                    <h2><?php echo "Tag: " . $current_tag; ?></h2>
              <h2><?php echo "Category: " . $category->name; ?></h2>
              <ul>
              <?php
                echo '<ul>';
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                    $the_query->the_post();
                    echo '<li>Post title: ' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
                }
                echo '</ul></ul></div><br>';
            } 
            ?>

        <?php } 
        wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Perfect Sidd! Finally what i looking for. Here the screenshots: http://prntscr.com/gvhz7m. Really really thank you so much!

Comment: cool. Glad i could help. It would be great if you could accept my answer :)

Comment: Im the one who should be thanks! I just PM you on facebook. I Hope we can get in touch more through facebook. Thanks!

Comment: we sure will. let me know if u need any help in future.

Comment: working for me after change attray value "$args=array(
                'cat' => $category->term_id,
                'post_type' => 'ourservices',
                //'posts_per_page'  => 10,
              //  'category_name' => 'our-services', // replace it with your category slug
                'orderby' => 'name',
                'order' => 'ASC'
            );"

Comment: @Sid Can we exclude parent category and post titles from parent category? Need to show only child categories.

Comment: $child_categories = get_categories( array('child_of' => $category->term_id) ); Add this after the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one and let me know if it helps.

```
<?php
        $categories = get_categories( array('hide_empty' => TRUE) );
    foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
    <?php
        $args=array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1, 
            'tag' => 'tutorial',
            'cat' => $category->term_id,
        );

        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            ?>
            <div class="CategoryPost">
          <h2><?php echo $category->name; ?></h2>
          <ul>
          <?php
            echo '<ul>';
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                $the_query->the_post();
                echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul></ul></div>';
        } 
        ?>

    <?php }
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

P.S. I have just printed the post title. If this works for you, please add other parameters to print as well.

Thanks

EDIT: to display for all tags.

```
   <?php 
        $tags_array = get_tags();
        $categories = get_categories( array('hide_empty' => TRUE) );
        foreach($tags_array as $tag){
        foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
        <?php
            $args=array(
                'posts_per_page' => -1, 
                'tag_id' => $tag->term_id,
                'cat' => $category->term_id,
            );

            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

            if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                ?>
                <div class="CategoryPost">
                    <h2><?php echo "Tag: " . $tag->name; ?></h2>
              <h2><?php echo "Category: " . $category->name; ?></h2>
              <ul>
              <?php
                echo '<ul>';
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                    $the_query->the_post();
                    echo '<li>Post title: ' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
                }
                echo '</ul></ul></div><br>';
            } 
            ?>

        <?php } }
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! The code is working exactly like i want but If theres a category without the post. The Category name still showing. Here the screenshots: http://prntscr.com/gvh99f. But is it a option that the code would working on all tags? I mean the 'tag' => 'tutorial', can be change to make it work on all tags?

Comment: change the first line to  
$categories = get_categories( 'hide_empty' => true );
As you looped through all categories, you can loop through all tags using get_tags() function.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I've got Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Comment: extremely sorry! that was my bad.

 $categories = get_categories( array( 'hide_empty' => true) );

Comment: nope. dont feel sorry. you help me a lot. Thank you very much. But it still not working. Still have same problem. The other category name shown up. Am i skip something?

Comment: Hmm.. I am confused too. the code is working for me. Please check the updated code in my answer above. Use as it is and let me know the result.

Comment: Hmm still show other category name.. Screenshot here: http://prntscr.com/gvhhk3

Comment: my bad again. Find the updated code in my answer above. This should work

Comment: Finally! Thank you very much. Beside I wait your code, I try to loop get_tags(); to replace 'tag' => 'tutorial', but the code make all posts shown up. even not use tutorial tags.

Comment: I have added another code block in my above answer to loop through all tags on the site. Please let me know if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Perfectly like I wanted to show. But it show others tag. For Example the link is localhost/tags/tutorial/. I just want to show tutorial tags posts.  Screenshots here http://prntscr.com/gvhr4j Anyway sorry if I ask you a lot until now. Honestly its my first time playing with wordpress code. You help me a lot till now. really really apreciate your help..

Comment: update with multiple post and different tags to make you understand what is it looks like. Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/gvhs57

Comment: Oh okay.. now i get it.. Give me 5 mins. I will get back to you wid updated code.

Comment: and FYI. If the post are in same category i would like to make it on same section or same div so there is no twice or duplicate Category name shown up..

Comment: I have added a new answer. take a look.

Answer (score 0):

@GaroPpo Here, is tweaked code which I suggested to you. I hope this will full-fill you requirement.

```
<?php
    $tag_id = array(12, 13, 14);
    $taxonomy = 'testimonial-category';
    $postType = 'testimonial';
    $terms = get_terms(['taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'orderby' => 'term_id', 'hide_empty' => true]);
?> <div class="add-accordion"> <?php
    foreach($terms as $term){
        if($term->parent == 0){
            echo '<h3>' . $term->name . '</h3>';
            continue;
        }  $posts = get_posts(array('post_status' =>'publish','post_type' => $postType, 'tag__in' => $tag_id,
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms' => $term->term_id,
                ),));
        ?>
        <div class="add-accordion">
            <h3><?php echo $term->name ?></h3>
            <div class="add-accordion">
                <?php foreach($posts as $post){ ?>
                    <h3><?php echo $post->post_title ?></h3>
                    <div class="">
                        <?php echo get_the_content($post->ID) ?>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I try to understand the code. Hopefully i can try this code.. Appreciate your help a lot!

Comment: Thanks! I try to understand the code. Hopefully i can try this code.. Appreciate your help a lot!